# Select row with max value from each group in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have table `people` containing people, their city and their money balance:

```
id    city_id    money
1     1          25
2     1          13
3     2          97
4     2          102
5     2          37
```

Now, I would like to select richest person from each city. How can I do that using Oracle SQL? Desired result is:

```
id    city_id    money
1     1          25
4     2          102
```

Something like that would be useful:

```
SELECT * as tmp FROM people GROUP BY city_id HAVING money = MAX(money)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be thinking "filtering", not "aggregation", because you want the entire row.  You can use a subquery:

```
select p.*
from people p
where p.money = (select max(p2.money) from people p2 where p2.city_id = p.city_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK()` as its flexible as you can get richest or top N richest

```
SELECT
 id, city_id, money
   FROM (
    SELECT 
    p.* ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY money DESC ) as rank_per_city
    FROM 
    people p )
WHERE
rank_per_city = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function through grouping by `city_id`(*by using `partition by` clause*) and ***descendingly*** ordering by `money` within the subquery to pick the returned values equal to 1 within the main query in order to determine the richest person including ***ties***(*the people having the same amount of money in each city*) such as

```
SELECT id, city_id, money
  FROM( SELECT p.*,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY money DESC ) AS dr
          FROM people p )  
 WHERE dr = 1
```

Comment: please check out  again whether the same @Yefet and compare the results through [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b565e9db506f31c27474bf4e0c88c7fa)